# Incremental loading of images

Tags: android, image, lazy-loading

In my app I need to download a lot of images for data in a ListView. I do lazy loading and it works rather fast, but still there is a 1-3 secs delay before the first image shows up. My research in the delay shows that the data transfer takes 50% of the time.

Now, I believe that If I could do incremental loading of the images, I would be able to show half an image after just 75% of the delay, which is quite good.

I use `Drawable.createFromStream` which uses `BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream` internally. But even though it takes a stream, it doesn't paint anything before all data is downloaded and decoded.

Do you know a way to load and paint images incrementally with the default Android lib? Or perhaps a good independent one out there?

[image: Screenshot of an ImageDownloader app]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GTM_W5mVPTU/TETLoIzCOaI/AAAAAAAAAIU/1_u5-WwQT_I/s400/thr.png))</sub>

Comment: By "incremental" you mean it show a partial image loading while it's loading?  I think you'd need an external library for doing that; I can't think of anything in the default Android lib for it.  BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream() decodes the entire stream into a Bitmap, which is then turned into a BitmapDrawable, which is why you don't see partial images using it.

Comment: Exactly. Similar to the way browsers load images (pixel) line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't answer the question you asked.  However, is it possible for you to populate with a reduced-quality/downsampled or reduced-size thumbnail, or a dummy/loading image so that a placeholder exists while the loading occurs?  This is how I work around that in my app.

Comment: I guess this is the only approachable way for now. Perhaps Google will add API's for continuous loading of their WebP files later.

Answer (score 0):

For the download process, check [WebImageView](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/) by DroidFu.

Comment: It does show a nice loading icon, but I'm not sure whether it does incremental loading?

Comment: @Thomas Ahle: Just pointing you to widgets already created so you can base your code on it.

Comment: Ah thanks, I misunderstood you.
However, it seams like WebImageView uses BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream internally as well.